# Change all date format in a column Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, date

I need to change the time column format from `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss` to `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` in PowerShell.

### Current CSV

```
Time,EZSpeed
2019/07/31 06:25:00,0643
2019/07/31 03:41:31,0643
```

### Needs to to look like

```
Time,EZSpeed
7/31/2019 06:25:00,0643
7/31/2019 03:41:31,0643
```

### My code

```
$combined = "mydocuments\doc.csv"

Import-Csv $combined | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.Time.ToString('mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')
} | Export-Csv -Path "mydocuments\doc.csv"
```

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Answer (score 1):

This fixed my issue:

```bsh
Import-Csv $combined | % { 
    $_.Time = ([DateTime]($_.Time)).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM');
    $_
}
```